# Admob Linker Error

Tags: linker, admob

I'm implementing Admob to my iphone app. It works in the simulator at iOS 4.0 (with target SDK 3.0), which shows I've correctly followed the beginners tutorial at http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html. However when trying to run on a device which has iOS 4.3.1 I get 2 linker errors:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/home/Documents/iPhoneDocs/Admobs/googleadmobadssdkios/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a,
>   file was built for unsupported file format which is not the
>   architecture being linked (armv7) Undefined symbols for architecture
>   armv7:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What does this mean and how do I fix it?
One thing I don't understand is that the file it's referencing is valid, but I was expecting it to reference the one in my project directory.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add libGoogleAdMobAds.a to framework. Drag **libGoogleAdMobAds.a** to **Link Binary With Libraries**. Check following image

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/images/frameworks2.png

Answer (score 6):

For those who are getting this error when trying to use AdMob through CocoaPods the answer is to include the libGoogleAdMobAds.a library to the Pod (specifically Pods-AdMob).  It seems that's not added automatically.

edit: Some more detail - you need to go into the Pods project, Build Phases, choose the Ad Mob library, then in link binary with Libraries press the + button, choose Add Other..., then navigate to the Pod directory and the Google Ad Mob directory within there, then add the libGoogleAdMobAds.a file.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It happen to me when I try to implement AdMob on my project. I was using Xcode 6, build target iOS 6.0. After trying to fix it. I found that It missing:

```
-lGoogleAdMobAds
```

in Other linker flags.

So the step are:

- Press cmd + 1
- Selected App Target (not Pods)
- Goto Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags
- Add "-lGoogleAdMobAds" (without ")

Hope the problem solve.